# How to create a weak entity in mySql?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to know how can I create weak entities in mySql by Creating tables, I have the code like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_Id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    full_Name varchar(60),
    email varchar(30),
    password varchar(30),
    reg_Date timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE personal_Infos(

   ...
);
```

These are the tables, all I want to Know is how can I Connect to each-other with foreign key and should I create another primary key at the second table? (Second table has some more informations for the first table)

Comment: 1) What do you mean by a "weak entity"? 2) You'll need to show us at least _some_ of the definition of `personal_Infos`, and explain how it relates to `users`, for us to give any useful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I create another primary key at the second table?

Yes you do need to create a primary key in your second table `personal_Infos` table and that primary key will become foreign key in your `users` table.

> how can I Connect to each-other with foreign key ?

Suppose your primary key in `personal_Infos` table is `P_id`, then you can add it as foreign key in your `users` table like shown below

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_Id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    full_Name varchar(60),
    email varchar(30),
    password varchar(30),
    reg_Date timestamp,
    p_id int not null,
FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES personal_Infos(P_Id)
);
```

Comment: The pair of columns `(user_Id, p_id)` represents a relationship. As currently implemented, it can be a one-to-many relationship since the same `p_id` can occur multiple times, allowing the same `p_id` value to be associated with many different `user_Id` values. To turn it into a one-to-one relationship, a unique constraint can be added on the `p_id` column. Note that the FK constraint in the table definition doesn't connect or relate rows, it only ensures `p_id` values are a subset of those in the `personal_Infos` table.

Comment: Whether it's a `1:1` or `1:many` relationship depends on what type of data `personal_Infos` table contains. If the data in any one row of `personal_Infos` table can be associated with more than one `user_Id`'s in `users` table, then it's `1:many` relationship. If the data in any one row in `personal_Infos` table can only be associated with any one `user_Id` in `users` table, then it's a `1:1` relationship.